# (include_path='.:/usr/local/php5_3/lib/php') in /home/content/06/11735806/html/systems/CA/pdf.php

Tags: php, include, tcpdf

> require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening required
>   `tcpdf_include.php`
>
> (include_path='.:/usr/local/php5_3/lib/php') in
>   /home/content/06/11735806/html/systems/CA/pdf.php
>
> I am getting this error and my link is http://caware.in/pinal.php .
>   Please help me as soon as possible with the perfect solution.

Comment: please post the code that you tried, without which no one can help

Comment: require_once('PDF/config/lang/eng.php');
require_once('PDF/tcpdf.php');

Comment: class MYPDF extends TCPDF {

    // Page footer
    public function Footer() {
        // Position at 15 mm from bottom
        $this->SetY(-15);
        // Set font
        $this->SetFont('helvetica', 'I', 8);
        // Page number
        $this->Cell(0, 10, 'Page '.$this->getAliasNumPage().'/'.$this->getAliasNbPages(), 0, false, 'C', 0, '', 0, false, 'T', 'M');
    }
}

Comment: And please don't ask as _Do my job please. I want it to be perfect._

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In TCPDF there is tcpdf_iclude.php and if you open that file you can see something as

```
    $tcpdf_include_dirs = array(realpath('../tcpdf.php'), 
'/usr/share/tcpdf/tcpdf.php', 
'/usr/share/php-tcpdf/tcpdf.php', '/var/www/tcpdf/tcpdf.php', 
'/var/www/html/tcpdf/tcpdf.php', 
'/usr/local/apache2/htdocs/tcpdf/tcpdf.php');
```

Now check where is your TCPDF folder then add the path in that config file and it will solve the issue.
if its inside /home/content/06/11735806/html/systems/CA

then add the following on the include dirs as

```
/home/content/06/11735806/html/systems/CA/tcpdf/tcpdf.php
```

Comment: hey i am working on file-zilla on godaddy server. I am not getting the file what u r asking to change in.

Comment: also I am not having TCPDF folder and include file

Comment: the folder name could be different. where is your tcpdf library or in which folder ?

Answer (score 0):

Check that you are linking to the right file in your `require_once()` function.

Comment: yeah its correct still its not working